# How to push one event into two different Google Analytics Accounts?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

I've implemented the following on my site, to pass an Event to two different Google-Analytics accounts.

In my GA-Trackingcode in the head section there are **two different accounts** defined:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX1-1']);   
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);  


_gaq.push(['account2._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX2-1']);
_gaq.push(['account2._trackPageview']);
```

my event is the following:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'xyz', 'xyzz'],
['account2._trackEvent', 'Download', 'xyz', 'xyzz']);">
Download_Fible_Fluegas</a>
```

But the code does **only** push the Event to the UA-XXXXX1-1 Account not (like i expected) to both accounts! Why?!?!

Someone out there who can help?

-Thanks

**EDIT**

This is the new implementation which i am **testing** like Google tells me in their docs https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?hl=de-DE#MultipleCommands

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX3-1'], ['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'xyz', 'xyzz'],['account2._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX2-1'],['account2._trackEvent', 'Download', 'xyz', 'xyzz']);">Link_to_download</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried two separate push calls?

Comment: Not yet, I thought this will work cause google tells in its devguides "Instead of typing _gaq.push(...) for each call, you can push all of your commands at once" https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?hl=de-DE#MultipleCommands

Comment: Hm strange one.. it even explicitly says: "Pushing commands to multiple trackers also works".

Comment: Yes it does...this problem gives me a headache!

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe you need to add a setAccount before each trackEvent so GA knows where to push the event to (just like the trackPageview-Example in the Google Docs) ?

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff, Do you have a link for me to the trackPageview-Example in Google Docs?

Comment: Also tried like you mentioned Eike Pierstorff:
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX3-1'], ['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'xyz', 'xyzz'],['account2._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX4-1'],['account2._trackEvent', 'Download', 'xyz', 'xyzz']);">Download_Fible_Fluegas</a>

But dosnt Work! ...even more headache! Why do google write this in there docs, when it dosnt work?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_trackPageview` and `_trackEvent` work by requesting a tracking pixel from the Google Analytics servers -- if your link is opening a new page in the same window or causing a download, then the browser can be canceling the tracking pixel requests prematurely before data can be captured, and you've been lucky timing-wise that the first request has gone through.

The common solution is to delay the processing of the link by a short amount of time (like 150ms) in order to allow the requests to be made.

Something like

```
function trackMe(link) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'xyz', 'xyzz'], ['account2._trackEvent', 'Download', 'xyz', 'xyzz']);
  setTimeout(function(){document.location = link.href}, 150);
  return false;
}

<a href="#" onClick="return trackMe(this);">Download_Fible_Fluegas</a>
```